# two same KML files from different sources, one can display, the other can't

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps

I need to use KML layers on my react app and try the example from https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#kmllayer (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml).

```js
const { compose, withProps } = require("recompose");
const {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  KmlLayer,
} = require("../index");

const MapWithAKmlLayer = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC4R6AN7SmujjPUIGKdyao2Kqitzr1kiRg&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={9}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 41.9, lng: -87.624 }}
  >
    <KmlLayer
      url="http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml"
      options={{ preserveViewport: true }}
    />
  </GoogleMap>
);

<MapWithAKmlLayer />
```

The example works fine, some lines are displayed on the map. However, the problem occurs on the URL. Because I need to use my KML file (my own path), I save the cta.kml file on my localhost server, on the root of assets folder. It can't display any lines I use node as backend app.

```
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/assets`));
```

For example, if I input http://localhost:3000/cta.kml, the file will be downloaded directly like inputting http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml given by the example. However, if I put 'http://localhost:3000/cta.kml' as URL on the KmlLayer's URL property, google map can't show any lines. I don't know why is that since two files are exactly same. I also tried other example URLs, and the same thing happened. For example, the KML file URL given by this example (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here: [ng-map only opens remote KML file but not local file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572538/ng-map-only-opens-remote-kml-file-but-not-local-file). 
"place the KML file on a public server where google server can access it since parsing of KML and rendering is done by the Google server."